# Is it possible to install Visual Studio Code on Debian 10 buster 32-bit machine?

Tags: debian, software-installation, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to install Visual Studio Code on a Debian 10 32-bit machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the source code from this project [VSCodium](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium).

> This [VSCodium] is not a fork. This is a repository of scripts to automatically build Microsoft's vscode repository into freely-licensed binaries with a community-driven default configuration.

But you can only build 32 bit binaries up to version [1.35.1](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_linux-32bit-support-ends)

> Linux 32-bit support ends:
> VS Code is using the Electron framework to run on multiple platforms. With this release, we move to Electron version 4.x, which means that VS Code will no longer run on Linux 32-bit.

Comment: Thank you for helping.